# How to hit asp.net web api action?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I'm new to web api, so I trying to catch action (action with name Test) in web api controller with no success, always get  *The resource cannot be found. 404 error*

This is my controller:

```
public class ReadController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Test()
    {

        return Ok();
    }
    // GET: api/Read
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {

        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET: api/Read/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST: api/Read
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // PUT: api/Read/5
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE: api/Read/5
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }
```

This is my WebApiConfig class

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Trying with this call

https://localhost:44300/api/Read/Test

https://localhost:44300/api/Test

in both cases I get 404 error

Comment: are you sure your `WebApiConfig.Register` is being called? (Generally from within your `Application_Start` in global.asax)

Comment: I highly recommend using Attribute Routing instead of magic string routes.   http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: Yes, WebApiConfig.Register is called.

Comment: you should add routing attribute to your test method.  something like this  [Route("test")].

Comment: I tried with route attribute  [Route("test")] and route prefix above controller [RoutePrefix("api")] I got same result 404

Comment: what url are you trying to call now..

https://localhost:44300/api/Test

Comment: yes, that url call  localhost:44300/api/Test

Comment: [RoutePrefix("api")]
public class ReadController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("test")]
    public IHttpActionResult Test()
    {

        return Ok();
    }
......

if this is what your controller looks like you are doing it right, it works for me.

Comment: it just looks like my controller.....

Comment: This is my Global.asax file `  public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            //GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        }
    }`

Comment: it looks like you first created a MVC application and now trying to add a web api endpoint to it right?

Comment: if you want to web api only project , there is a web api template try that.

Comment: yes you are right. What is the problem with that?

Comment: If its a web api its a service so its hosted separately from the web solution where it is consumed, that how we should do.

But to answer you its definitely some missing references, you cannot just add routing in MVC application for web api to get it working. Probably you can setup a web api project see if it works and figure what the differences between the two.

Comment: Posting code in the comments won't help much. You can edit your question accordingly.